# Android Java Unit Testing using ApplicationProiver

Tags: unit-testing, androidx

I am trying to use the new Androidx testing.  When I run the following unit test, I get the following error.  I don't know why the context package name is org.robolectric.default

junit.framework.ComparisonFailure:

Expected :com.example.test_game_java

Actual   :org.robolectric.default

```
package com.example.test_game_java;
import android.content.Context;
import org.junit.Test;
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.Assert.*;

//import static androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider.*;
import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleUnitTest {

    @Test
    public void applicationContextTest() {
        Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
        assertEquals("com.example.test_game_java", context.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add testOptions.unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true under 
android {} in the gradle file